# Any way to create a revision of a post ONLY with a new button in the Meta Box?

Tags: posts, customization, admin, version-control, revisions

Quite sure there isn't a way baked in to do this, but anyone have any ideas on how I would get something like this done? I want to turn autorevisions off and ONLY have a revision created when a button is clicked (probably custom button placed in the meta box). Would be a super useful way to do more of a version control scenario with the posts instead of revisions every time you fix a spelling error.

For instance, could we use this and tie it to a button click?

```
   /**
 * Saves an already existing post as a post revision.
 *
 * Typically used immediately prior to post updates.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Post_Revisions
 * @since 2.6.0
 *
 * @uses _wp_put_post_revision()
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post to save as a revision.
 * @return mixed Null or 0 if error, new revision ID, if success.
 */
function wp_save_post_revision( $post_id ) {
    // We do autosaves manually with wp_create_post_autosave()
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // WP_POST_REVISIONS = 0, false
    if ( ! WP_POST_REVISIONS )
        return;

    if ( !$post = get_post( $post_id, ARRAY_A ) )
        return;

    if ( !post_type_supports($post['post_type'], 'revisions') )
        return;

    $return = _wp_put_post_revision( $post );

    // WP_POST_REVISIONS = true (default), -1
    if ( !is_numeric( WP_POST_REVISIONS ) || WP_POST_REVISIONS < 0 )
        return $return;

    // all revisions and (possibly) one autosave
    $revisions = wp_get_post_revisions( $post_id, array( 'order' => 'ASC' ) );

    // WP_POST_REVISIONS = (int) (# of autosaves to save)
    $delete = count($revisions) - WP_POST_REVISIONS;

    if ( $delete < 1 )
        return $return;

    $revisions = array_slice( $revisions, 0, $delete );

    for ( $i = 0; isset($revisions[$i]); $i++ ) {
        if ( false !== strpos( $revisions[$i]->post_name, 'autosave' ) )
            continue;
        wp_delete_post_revision( $revisions[$i]->ID );
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Would love to hear what you experts have to say!

Thanks

UPDATE: It seems as if this will be the way to go:
remove_action('pre_post_update', 'wp_save_post_revision');

But I'm having trouble tying that to a specific button.. I don't want to disable revisions completely, and I don't want it to apply every time any button is pressed, just momentarily when this button is pressed.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** yet a complete answer, for lack of time, though I'll try to return later with a more complete example but I just wanted to add a couple of notes. Possibly someone else will jump in soon.

To get the ball rolling...

#### Firstly,

Yes this is entirely possible, you can create this functionality and in your snippet you'll see some of the relevant hooks you need to be working with.

```
add_action('_wp_put_post_revision', 'your_function");
```

Found in [`../wp-includes/post.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post.php#L4856) along with other relevant hooks relating to revisions.

#### Secondly,

To add a <kbd>Save Revision</kbd> button next to or on top of the <kbd>Publish</kbd> button you would use the following hook;

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'custom_button' );

function custom_button(){
        $html  = '<div id="major-publishing-actions" style="overflow:hidden">';
        $html .= '<div id="publishing-action">';
        $html .= '<input type="submit" accesskey="p" tabindex="5" value="Customize Me!" class="button-primary" id="custom" name="publish">';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        echo $html;
}
```

That's a working example and the html formatting (`divs, id's, etc`) are there to preserve some kind of consistent UI experience but feel free to change any of that to your liking, especially if you want a custom look and feel or special padding, margins and so forth.

PS. Try and attempt, regardless of the outcome, to write your own function hooking onto  `_wp_put_post_revision` in conjunction with the custom button hook above. Paste your results in the meantime.

Comment: Hmmmm, above is what I've cobbled together so far.. It certainly creates a revision, but so does hitting the regular "update" button... But I guess that get's me half there perhaps? What say you userabuser?

Comment: It also seems like something simple like this would be useful, but I'm unable to produce any results with it either:

    remove_action('pre_post_update', 'wp_save_post_revision');// stop revisions
    add_action('pre_post_update', 'wp_save_post_revision');//  enable revisions again

Comment: Man, I am really struggling with this one. Any other tips you might offer? Thanks!